# Views AJAX pager is not working for custom theme

Tags: 7, views, ajax, paging

I am using a custom theme for my Drupal site. Here I have created views with page displays, Kept AJAX pager 'on'. When I click on next the pager keeps on loading.

In firebug I found the following error

`"$(scrollTarget).scrollTop is not a function

[Break On This Error]

...he page to get source for: http://mysite.co... "`

Totally no AJAX view pager is working in my theme, where in garland working fine.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Make sure you have printed all the scripts in custom theme.

Comment: Which version of Drupal you're using?

Comment: Maybe js should like "jQuery(scrollTarget).....?"

Comment: I have commented the above function, then pagers started working with AJAX. Everything is fine now.